# Como substituir um teclado por um UIPickerView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, teclado

Tenho um programa, que um trecho do formulário, no caso um `UITextField`, que precisa ser preenchido. Mas em vez de surgir um teclado, preciso que apareça um `UIPickView`, que já possui as opções para o preenchimento.

Então no momento que o usuário for iniciar a ediçaõ deste `UITextField`, preciso que em vez do teclado, apareça um `UIPickView`.

O programa é para iOS, usando Objective-C.

Comment: Não entendi o voto de fora de escopo. Entendo que a pergunta é ampla demais, ou até não esteja clara o suficiente. No escopo ela deve estar, pois aparenta ser uma pergunta de programação.

Comment: Vou editar para melhorar a explicação.

Comment: Fiz uma edição na pergunta para melhorar o entendimento. Espero que tenha ficado mais claro agora.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema esta no iOS 8. Para resolver

```
pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];

[pickerView setDataSource: self];
[pickerView setDelegate: self];

[pickerView setFrame: CGRectMake(xPoint, 50.0f, pickerWidth, 200.0f)];

pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;

[pickerView selectRow:2 inComponent:0 animated:YES];

[self.view addSubview: pickerView];
UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,xPoint , pickerWidth)]; // add autorelease if you don't use ARC

v.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[v addSubview:pickerView];
editUFCRM.inputView = pickerView;
```

Answer (score 4):

Basta você adicionar o seu `UIPickerView` na propriedade `inputView` do `UITextField`. Supondo que tenha algo assim ao iniciar sua *View Controller*:

```
_picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, 270.0f)];
[_picker setDelegate:self];
[_picker setDataSource:self];
```

Adicione ao seu input:

```
[self.inputSelect setInputView:_picker];
```

Então, vai implementando o *delegate* apropriado para o seu caso.

Comment: Obrigado, vou testar aqui e ja digo se funcionou!

Comment: Desculpe esqueci do detalhe, era para iOS 8

Comment: Tudo bem, mas de qualquer forma o meu teste foi justamente no iOS 8, Xcode 6 GM.

Comment: O SOF poderia permitir mais de uma alternativa como resposta para o mesmo problema, já que tem coisas que podem ser feitas de 2 a 3 formas possiveis. :\